# MySQL ORDER BY string as number (larger numbers above smaller numbers)

Tags: mysql, innodb

Consider the following results where `code` is type `VARCHAR`:

```
SELECT code
FROM lock
ORDER BY CAST(code AS signed) > 0 DESC, `code

|code|
|4   |  
|420 |
|5   |
|T6  |
|X30 |
```

How can I change the query so that it returns the results in this order:

```
|code|
|4   |  
|5   |
|420 |
|T6  |
|X30 |
```

Comment: Note: I had posted a similar question on another account which I created by accident (requested to be deleted), please note this question is slightly different

Comment: `SELECT CAST(code AS signed) as code
FROM lock
HAVING code > 0
ORDER BY code  ASC`

Comment: @rockerBOO This removes `T6` and `X30` (but does order the numbers correctly)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT code
FROM lock
ORDER BY CAST(code AS signed) > 0 DESC, CAST(code AS signed) ASC, code ASC
```

The first order will sort the numbers to the front. The second order will only sort the numbers ascending, while the first will keep them at the start. The third will only sort the strings ascending, the numbers will keep their order because they are already sorted.

Answer (score 0):

E.g.:

```
SELECT *
     , code+0 
     , code+0=0
  FROM (SELECT '4' code UNION 
        SELECT '420'    UNION 
        SELECT '5'      UNION 
        SELECT 'T6'     UNION 
        SELECT 'X30') n 
 ORDER 
    BY code+0=0
     , code+0
     , code;

+------+--------+----------+
| code | code+0 | code+0=0 |
+------+--------+----------+
| 4    |      4 |        0 |
| 5    |      5 |        0 |
| 420  |    420 |        0 |
| T6   |      0 |        1 |
| X30  |      0 |        1 |
+------+--------+----------+
```

Answer (score -1):

`LENGTH()` function in SQL is used to get the length of a string:

```
SELECT code
FROM lock
ORDER BY LENGTH(code), code
```

**OUT:**

```
+------+
| code |
+------+
| 4    |
| 5    |
| T6   |
| 420  |
| X30  |
+------+
```

Comment: In the example in the question `T6` is shorter than `420`, will it be after `420`?

Comment: Edit:Sample QUERY Out

Comment: I'm sorry but this answer is wrong, it's not what the user wanted.